# create a row index column beginning at -1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to create a row index column that begins at -1 so i can query the previous day's balance. My current query:

```
select TRANSDATE, sum(convert(float,AMOUNTMST-SETTLEAMOUNTMST)) as Balance

from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V]

group by TRANSDATE

order by TRANSDATE asc

TRANSDATE                Balance
2019-04-12 00:00:00.000 -22591.47
2019-04-15 00:00:00.000 -394.95
2019-04-25 00:00:00.000 -1776
2019-04-26 00:00:00.000 -11973.84
2019-04-29 00:00:00.000 -24230.16
2019-05-02 00:00:00.000 -10695.39
```

This is what i need:

```
TRANSDATE                Balance   Row Index
2019-04-12 00:00:00.000 -22591.47    -1
2019-04-15 00:00:00.000 -394.95       0
2019-04-25 00:00:00.000 -1776         1 
2019-04-26 00:00:00.000 -11973.84     2
2019-04-29 00:00:00.000 -24230.16     3
2019-05-02 00:00:00.000 -10695.39     4
```

I have tried to declare a variable as the row index

```
declare @row_num as int = -1
select TRANSDATE, sum(convert(float,AMOUNTMST-SETTLEAMOUNTMST)) as Balance, @row_num += 1 as Row Index

from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V]

group by TRANSDATE
```

i receive this error:

```
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.
```

after declaring a variable for each field I still receives errors. Is there an easier way to accomplish this? thanks

Comment: Aren't you just after `ROW_NUMBER()` minus 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`. For example:

```
select
  TRANSDATE, 
  sum(convert(float,AMOUNTMST-SETTLEAMOUNTMST)) as Balance, 
  row_number() over(order by TRANSDATE) - 2 as Row Index
from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[CUSTTRANS_V]
group by TRANSDATE
```